# how to convert level meter to Hz in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, frequency, recording, audioqueue

I'm using AudioQueue to get recording level meter via microphone. The problem is what I got from it are floating point numbers. I know they represents for audio sample.

I need to convert it to Hz. My assignment is to convert a digital signal audio recording from microphone. Convert it to Hz and do a simple formula to get a result that relevant to this number.

Please help, I really appreciate your help.

Thanks,

Quan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An audio recording from a microphone will not contain a single frequency that you can represent in Hz.

Instead, it will be a combination of a lot of different frequencies mixed together, which are represented by your samples.

To get the frequencies in your sample and their amplitude, you need to use the [Fast Fourier transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform).  From the results you can determine which frequencies are most prevalent in your sample, which I believe is what you are looking for.